# Тип выделенного предложения:

Tags: синтаксис

Она разорвала конверт, *ожидая длинного письма*.

У нас "ожидая" называется "партицип", но совсем не знаю, как в русском языке называют такие предложения. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы носитель какого языка, смею поинтересоваться? Выделенная часть в вопросе не является предложением, это деепричастный оборот (полное название — обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом). *Ожидая* — это слово, относящееся к деепричастию. Надеюсь, вам понятно.

Comment: я испанка : ) сеичас буду искать в словаре как переводятся эти термины ; ) Вам большое спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: У вас вроде причастие так называется, а деепричастие, как я посмотрел в словаре, по-испански "gerundio", нет?

Comment: ufff claro, "esperando" у нас gerundio, не participio... спасибо за корректуру!!!

Comment: Рад стараться. :))